# Using os.listdir() to read images from LFW dataset can only read images from the first file folder

Tags: python, dataset, readfile

LFW dataset put images in different folders based on names. I want to read and move all images to one folder. I used a for loop with `os.listdir()` function to read the file, but it only returns an image from the first folder in LFW dataset.

```
'''code is showing below the line'''

    import os
    from os.path import join as pjoin
    from skimage import io
    img_dir = 'new path'
    def load_data(data_dir): #dataset is the originalPath

        count = 0
        for guys in os.listdir(data_dir):
            print(guys)
            person_dir = pjoin(data_dir, guys)
            for i in os.listdir(person_dir):
                image_dir = pjoin(person_dir, i)
                img22 = io.imread(image_dir, mode='RGB')
                print(image_dir)
                io.imsave(pjoin(img_dir, i), img22)
                count = count+1
            print(person_dir)
            print(count)
            return count

    sourcepath = 'originalPath'
    load_data(sourcepath)
```

The expected result is all images from all folders of LFW dataset are read to the new path (not in any folder, only images.)
The code runs with no error, but the count actually returns '1' and I can see in the new path, there's only 1 image, which was in the first folder of the LFW dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious problem is indentation of your return statement:

```
'''code is showing below the line'''

    import os
    from os.path import join as pjoin
    from skimage import io
    img_dir = 'new path'
    def load_data(data_dir): #dataset is the originalPath

        count = 0
        for guys in os.listdir(data_dir):
            print(guys)
            person_dir = pjoin(data_dir, guys)
            for i in os.listdir(person_dir):
                image_dir = pjoin(person_dir, i)
                img22 = io.imread(image_dir, mode='RGB')
                print(image_dir)
                io.imsave(pjoin(img_dir, i), img22)
                count = count+1
            print(person_dir)
        print(count)
        return count

    sourcepath = 'originalPath'
    load_data(sourcepath)
```

Can you check and confirm if the first folder (guys) it is working for has more than one images.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dinesh. I didn't realize there is a "return count", I was supposed to print(count) and return. After removing the return count the code works well.